# What does the <frontName> tag mean in config.xml?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, configuration

What does the  tag exactly mean in config.xml?

Would it be possible to put it in the  instead of the  section? What is the differece?

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <mymodule>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
                <frontName>admin_mymodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </mymodule>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

THanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When a router parses a URL, it gets separated as follows
>
> http://example.com/frontName/actionControllerName/actionMethod/ So, by
>   defining a value of "helloworld" in the  tags, we're
>   telling Magento that we want the system to respond to URLs in the form
>   of
>
> http://example.com/helloworld/* Many developers new to Magento confuse
>   this frontName with the Front Controller object. They are not the same
>   thing. The frontName belongs solely to routing.

For more information check here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html

Comment: Is it the one and only config element used for URL rewriting? Thx!